# CSV Post reload

Tags: php, csv

hallo guys sorry for bothering ..the code is now working..i had so many problems on my previous posts but this is the last problems i  am getting..i noticed when i insert the csv file it correctly inserting..but if i refresh the page data is being duplicated due to post data..how do i make this not to repeat? i am trying to paste this but i get an error

```
SAVED_REQUEST = $_REQEUST;
$SAVED_POST = $_POST;
$SAVED_GET = $_GET;
// FINALLY, IN YOUR LAST LINE ERASE THE PROBLEM VARIABLES...
$_REQUEST = $_POST = $_GET = NULL;
<?php $_REQUEST = $_POST = $_GET = NULL; ?>
```

this is my previous script

```
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" >
           CSV<input type="file" name="file" />
           <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
          </form>
          <?php
          $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
          or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
          $db = mysql_select_db("map", $connection)
          or die ("Couldn't select database");
          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
          {
          $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
          $handle = fopen($file,"r");
          if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

          while ($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"))
          {
          $a = $fileop[0];
          $b = $fileop[1];
          $c = $fileop[2];
          $d = $fileop[3];
          $e = $fileop[4];
          $f = $fileop[5];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hzy3o_zhgooglemaps_markers (title,   addresstext, published, baloon, icontype, mapid)
values('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f')");

           }

         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successful insert make redirect to the same page:

```
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourpage"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
```

Also make a check in database to prevent data duplication.

Your refactored code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== false) {
    while ($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'")) {
        list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f) = $fileop;
        $sql = mysql_query("
            INSERT INTO hzy3o_zhgooglemaps_markers (title,  addresstext, published, baloon, icontype, mapid)
            values('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f')
        ");

    }
}
}
?>

<?php if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0):?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" >
    CSV<input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php else: ?>
<?php
header("Location: http://www.shambani.org /index.php?option=com_zhgooglemap&view=zhgooglemap&id=1&mapzoom=13&placemarklistid=&explacemarklistid=&grouplistid=&categorylistid=¢erplacemarkid=¢erplacemarkaction=&externalmarkerlink=0&mapwidth=&mapheight=&Itemid=177");
exit();
?>
```

Try it.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi..are you there?

Comment: thanks alot i have edited abit and now its functioning....thank you and thank you and thank you..

Comment: very perfect!!!..thanks alot i dont know how to buy you something like a drink or anything..but thanks alot

Comment: If you have more questions and I have time I will try to answer them. And you will accept them to give me more reputation points;)

Comment: ok..but how will i know..will i use @oleksii.svarychevskyi ...and it will direct to you ?

Comment: It should. But I don't know exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
many thanks to  gurus who Assisted me to Develope this.. i thank you very much
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
$db = mysql_select_db("map", $connection)
or die ("Couldn't select database");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

while ($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"))
{
$a = $fileop[0];
$b = $fileop[1];
$c = $fileop[2];
$d = $fileop[3];
$e = $fileop[4];
$f = $fileop[5];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hzy3o_zhgooglemaps_markers (title,  addresstext,     published, baloon, icontype, mapid)

 values('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f')");

}
}
}

?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
  header("Location:       http://localhost/map/"); /* Redirect browser */
  exit();
 }

 ?>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" >
 CSV<input type="file" name="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
 </form>
```